# How do I quantify the amount of information in the following expression?

Tags: information-theory, kolmogorov-complexity, compression

Suppose that $N = \mbox{factorial}(9999999999)$. The number $N$ is mindbogglingly huge and, yet, can be represented very neatly and compactly as $\mbox{factorial}(9999999999)$. I have two questions:

1. How much "information" is "factorial()"?
2. Approximately how much compression did we achieve here?

I thought I could perhaps write and compile a program to get the factorial of a number $N$ and compare the (size of the executable + size of $9999999999$) with the number of bits used to store $N$. But, this would vary with the language used and there's also stuff in the executable other than the factorial definition. So, how do I quantify the amount of information that something like factorial(x) comprises?

PS: Please excuse the dumb question. I just find it fascinating that such large numbers can have such compact representations.

Comment: $9999999999! \approx 10^{95657055176}$ or $2^{317765859065}$.

Comment: How would you compress/decompress the enormous amount of numbers that are between $999999999\color{red}{8}!$ and $9999999999!$ ? I believe that the information you are storing is far smaller than you think.

Comment: Graham's number is unimaginably larger and it can be written as $G_{64}$. Of course the factorial leads to a huge compression. Why is this surprising ? The factorial grows exponential. We could say the same for the largest known prime, it can also be written quite compact.

Comment: @Peter sorry, I didn't do a very good job at writing that question. I wasn't focusing on factorial specifically. I was interested in all extremely large numbers in general, which can be calculated using a simple "rule" and quantifying the amount of "information" this rule contains. For example, a compiled C++ program which has a recursive function to calculate Graham's number would be a few KB at most. But G64 itself would be pretty difficult to store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notion you’re looking for is called Kolmogorov complexity.

The idea is that you consider some collection of expressions which evaluate to at most one value (but which could potentially not evaluate to a value - for example, $1/0$). For example, we may allow expressions to be formed using base-10 number notation, addition, multiplication, subtraction, division, and factorial. So $”9999999999!”$ would be an expression in the language which would evaluate to the number $9999999999!$.

We define the complexity of a number to be the length of the shortest expression which evaluates to that number. It seems very likely (though I haven’t proved it yet) that the complexity of $9999999999!$ would be 11 relative to our language. We could compare this to the actual number of digits in this number, which is approximately $10^{12}$, to see how much compression we have achieved.

Note that the most general case we would consider for a language of expressions would be a programming language like Python, Haskell, Java, etc. (or at least an idealised version of these languages without IO or randomness). With a programming language, we could define factorial within the language and use it, so we would be able to put a number on how much information it takes to encode $factorial$ itself. The downside to using a programming language for our expressions is that there is no algorithm to determine whether an expression actually represents a value or will run into an infinite loop when evaluated.

Keep in mind that compression will always depend on the specifics of the data layout. If I wanted to, I could come up with a new data format consisting of base-10 number notation and the symbol $n$, where $n$ is meant to denote $9999999999!$. Then, I could represent the number in question with only a single character (by design). But this would be a pretty stupid encoding system.

Comment: I can't thank you enough for this post. "Kolmogorov complexity" is exactly what I was looking for and your post is extremely informative and easy to understand. It's been bugging me for so long and it doesn't help that I'm terrible at expressing my thoughts.

Comment: (+1) Some additional remarks : The Kolmogorove complexity is uncomputable and almost all large numbers have a Kolmogorov complexity not much smaller than the complexity of the program "print <given number>" , such numbers are also called random (in the sense that they cannot be significantly compressed).

Comment: @Peter so, how large would the complexity of Graham's number be with respect to the number itself?

Comment: @st0n3r You have already answered this. The Kolmogorov complexity of Graham's number is quite small , probably not larger than , say , $2\ 000$ whereas the magnitude of Graham's number is impossible to graps. But this is an exception !

Comment: @Peter thanks, I needed to make sure I wasn't getting something wrong. I don't know much math at all but find some of these topics quite fascinating. If you don't mind, can I ask another dumb question? Is there a way to know if a number is random or not? For example, we know G64 is not random because we know how to calculate it. But what if someone saw the number for the first time? Is there a way to tell?

Comment: @st0n3r In general, there is no way to determine whether a huge number is random although plenty of the huge numbers are. Graham's number is only so strongly compressible since it is defined over Knuth's up-arrow notation giving a short description. If you toss a coin to construct the binary digits of a large number, you will almost always get a random number (not siginificantly compressible)